# Public IP check in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, authentication, ip

I want the program to check the public IP against one provided. So far i can't even get this to work. I've put my own IP in place of 0.0.0.0 not leaving it in for security purposes. I've also had it put the IP in the text field to make sure it's at least retreiving the right IP which it is yet it's still saying not authorized.

```
Function GetIP() As String
    Dim IP As New WebClient
    Return IP.DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com/")
End Function

    Dim UserIP As String
    Dim AuthIP As String
    UserIP = GetIP().Replace("\n", "")
    AuthIP = "0.0.0.0"
    TextBox7.Text = UserIP
    If TextBox7.Text = "0.0.0.0" Then
        MsgBox("COOL!")
    Else
        MsgBox("This machine is not authorized!")
    End If
```

I'd greatly appreciate anyone who could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in what you're comparing.
If UserIP is the one they're inputting, then your comparisons may need to go like this:

```
 Dim UserIP As String
    Dim AuthIP As String
    UserIP = TextBox7.text
    AuthIP = GetIP().Replace("\n", "")
    If trim(UserIP) = AuthIP Then
        MsgBox("COOL!")
    Else
        MsgBox("This machine is not authorized!")
    End If
```

Comment: They aren't inputting the IP. The IP comes from the function. I only have the text box to verify what IP the function is pulling. I wanted to make sure it was pulling an IP and make sure there wasn't odd formatting like a space or anything.

Comment: Where is the comparison of IP addresses(the one provided?)?  Based on the code posted, I cannot see where the issue occurs.

Comment: UserIP is declared as the IP retrieved from GetIP. When I run the code it properly sets Textbox7 as my IP. The problem is when I compare the text in Textbox7 they don't match assuming AuthIP = My IP address. So AuthIP = my IP address and so does Textbox7 but I will get the message that the machine isn't authorized or that they don't match when as far as I can tell they do.

Comment: I'm sorry before I had If UserIP = AuthIP Then, I've been trying to have it compare it direct, to a string, any way i can to find out why it's not working when it compares the UserIP to the AuthIP. It's pulling the right IP, no odd formatting that I can tell, but when it compares UserIP to anything I put in there it won't work.